# chicken kashrus

Tags: kashrut-kosher, meat

When buying chicken from your local kosher butcher, what signs should one look for that would indicate there may be a question about the chicken's kashrus?  Does it matter whether one bought a whole chicken vs. pieces?

Answer (score 6):

While I'm *inclined* to believe that the certifying agency endorsement *should* be sufficient perhaps I am mistaken since the OU has new video related to this issue :

> [Together,
>   they elucidate in a clear and thorough
>   fashion the red flags in raw chicken
>   that YOU need to know. After watching
>   this video, you’ll have more
>   confidence in the kashrut of the meat
>   you serve.](http://www.oukosher.org/index.php/common/article/new_ou_kosher_dvd_explains_whats_wrong_with_this_chicken/)

And the [Star-K](http://www.star-k.com/kashrus/kk-beef-chickens.htm) notes that:

> Education Breaks, Tears &
>   Irregularities
>
> Even with the best intentions and the
>   most intensive hashgacha, problems can
>   arise on occasion. Halachic shailos,
>   questions, are addressed on a case by
>   case basis. Nevertheless, general
>   guidelines of what constitutes a
>   shaila can be provided to the
>   homemaker. A broken chicken bone with
>   no discoloration, or slight
>   discoloration and a jagged or fully
>   broken bone, presents no kashrus
>   problems; we would assume the bone was
>   broken in processing. However, a
>   broken bone that has begun to re-knit
>   itself does present a problem. If
>   there is a spot of coagulated blood
>   without a break, the blood has to be
>   washed away. If the break is
>   surrounded by an area of coagulated
>   blood, the chicken should be shown to
>   a Rav.
>
> Skin tears can occur in the plucking
>   machine. If the bone is not broken but
>   is dislocated from its socket, e.g.,
>   the drumstick or the wing from the
>   chicken’s body, a Rav should be
>   consulted. Similarly, a Rav should be
>   consulted if there is swelling at the
>   bottom of the drumstick, especially if
>   there is swelling with red or green
>   discoloration. It may not be evident,
>   but there is a marked difference
>   between a whole chicken and a whole
>   cut-up chicken processed in the plant.
>   If there is a problem with a wing of a
>   whole chicken, the complete chicken is
>   treif. With a cut-up chicken, only
>   that piece should be thrown away
>   because the cut-up tray is comprised
>   of different pieces. In a local
>   butcher shop, the housewife should
>   check whether the cut-up comes from
>   the same chicken or from various
>   pieces that make up the tray.
>
> The same is true with liver and
>   giblets that are sold with the
>   chicken. Those parts are packaged
>   separately in the plant and are not
>   the liver or giblets of that
>   particular chicken. It is imperative
>   to remove the liver pack before
>   roasting the chicken. A chicken that
>   is roasted with the liver in the
>   cavity must be brought to the Rav for
>   a decision regarding the chicken and
>   roaster; the liver is probably treif
>   and must be discarded. In certain
>   processing plants, the necks are
>   kashered with the whole chicken. In
>   that case, the jugular veins should be
>   slit three times or removed, and the
>   mokom hashechita (the slaughtering
>   site) washed off. At other facilities,
>   where the necks are cut off, a machine
>   clips off the mokom hashechita     and
>   the necks are kashered separately;
>   splitting of the neck is not
>   necessary.

Comment: I have discussed this with a Rav in the kashrus industry who certainly felt that there was no need and no point in double checking the kashrus of chickens sold under acceptable hashgacha. Consult your Rav if you have reason to be concerned.

Comment: All the same, @Yirmeyahu, if you have a _treifa_ right in front of you....wouldn't you like to know about it?

Comment: With the amount of supervision, and its effect on pricing, the consolation I would feel from seeing it myself is only the slightest.  After all what else could be going wrong that cannot be observed after the fact?

Comment: There's a lot of stuff that could go wrong that you wouldn't be able to tell the difference....hole in the _kurkuvan_, hole in a lung, hole in intestine....and you could tell if the שוחט was דורס? ...What you *can* see is just broken bones, coagulated blood, and the other stuff mentioned in your answer

Comment: The mashgichim are pretty good, but in plants that big they can't catch every one....some are _batul barov_ but when you see it in front of you you can't rely on that