# Why did they stop packing the gizard, neck and liver inside the chicken cavity?

Tags: history, kashrut-kosher, parts-of-the-body, poultry, transactions

Why did they stop packing the gizard, neck and liver inside the chicken cavity? I think this practice stopped about 25 years ago. When I was a novice cook, I didn't know that I had to first take out the liver and roast it separately, until I had a messy non-kosher chicken, and someone informed me about that. Mind you, they did put a warning on the packaging. I can understand that they stopped including the liver (though, I think they could have just left it outside the cavity. But what about the other parts?

Comment: Some still include the neck, of course it varies by company. Also, liver has "gentrified", even chicken liver can be expensive.

Comment: Those parts are harder to kasher ("kosherize") ....as you mentioned, liver has to be roasted, neck needs extra salt (hence discarded in the factory), and the gizzard ("heilige kurkuvan";) since it has no (very very little) blood, it has to be kashered separately from the other parts of the chicken...too hard to deal with for too little meat, and probably discarded

Comment: When you shecht your own, you can get the kurkuvan...very good in chicken soup ;)

Comment: @Shokhet you have a source that gizzard needs salting separately... I just thought it isn't connected to chicken anymore after the evisceration so it was salted separately. And don't recall seeing this in hilchos melicha

Comment: @Yoni Shach YD 75:5 (if gizzard doesn't have blood, the salting is to remove the blood from the surrounding fats); Shach YD 75:1 (most hold that the gizzard does have blood); Maharsha 75 ד"ה דבקורקבן says that if it wasn't salted, you could be מיקל. My rebbi told me that, based on the Maharsha, there is a מנהג to salt it separately from other pieces of meat, but there is no issue בדיעבד if it was salted with other pieces of meat.

Comment: @Shokhet Thanks... But gilyon maharsha ( who is rav shlomo eiger -- rabbi akiva Eiger's soon--..not mharsha) agrees with shach requiring Melicha midina only lenient with sfek sfeka . maharshal in shach 7 hills all maiayim can be salted together. Also neck what source for needs extra salt?

Comment: @Yoni Source for the minhag to salt the gizzard separately is not in the Gilyon Maharsha (who I knew was R Shlomo Eiger, thanks) but rather was instituted some time after [possibly based off of his comments], and I learned about it from my rebbi

Comment: @Yoni working on a source for the extra salt/neck now

Comment: From what I recall, the gizzard was "extra" salty. Though I can't recall if that applied to the ones inside the chicken cavity or when I bought a separate package of gizzards. I guess because there are so many "folds" its harder to wash off all the salt??

Comment: @DanF [This answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1670/5323) probably has something to do with your question

Comment: @Yoni Sorry for responding so late....just came back to this question while looking stuff up for a different question, and found that I left you hanging....in my notes, all it says is that the neck needs extra stuff (YD 65), which for Askenazim is three cuts in the neck, Sephardim is to pull out the veins from the neck (Rama 65:3 says removal of head is enough, but we make cuts also)

Comment: @Yoni Nothing about extra salt though, but I definitely heard that somewhere.....